# Adding json as a string to a parse field

Tags: ios, json, parse-platform

I am saving an array of data to parse that I will never need to query or update, only retrieve. Is there an issue with saving this data in a string field of a `PFObject` as JSON? My motivation for doing this vs using an array of `PFObject` is to avoid hitting Api request limits and query limits.

Comment: it seems reasonable to me.  essentially, you're just saving "some data" right, basically a blob?  for later retrieval?  not unlike saving a video or image.

Comment: There is no problem storing a JSON string (or any string for that matter) in a string field. But what makes you believe that using an array of PFObjects will trigger additional API requests ?

Comment: Thanks. I inserted about a 100 parent objects in a day while developing the app and ended up with 4500 requests according to the parse dashboard. I assume it counted each save of pfobject a request.